# Create a clickable link to telegram message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm working on a Telegram bot for structuring knowledge in a group chat and one of the user scenario which I want to implement: when receiving some command the bot returns a list of clickable links to specific messages in the group chat.

The problem is: can't make a clickable link to a telegram message.

I've tried 2 options so far:

1. Using aiogram `await bot.forward_message(...)` method

```
await bot.forward_message(chat_id=bot_chat_id, from_chat_id=group_chat_id, message_id=250)
```

The link the bot returns is not clickable. Just a quotation

2. Return a message with html format

```
await bot.send_message(chat_id=bot_chat_id, text="<a href='https://t.me/{}/250'>message URL</a>", parse_mode='HTML')
```

But the link is dead. Please tell me how to create a correct link to message.

BTW, even if you manually forward a message in a personal chat with a person - the link is not clickable. Only *Reply* option makes a clickable quotation.
Only if one forwards a message to *Saved Messages* "chat" - one can follow the link.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like it was a temporary bag in telegram: the link like `https://t.me/c/{target_chat_id}/{message_id}` actually works fine